# GWT Celltable How to make Non-Editable cell in Editable column

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I added EditTextCell(stringTestEditTextCell) to Column(testColumn).

> EditTextCell editTextCell = new EditTextCell();
>          Column stringColumn = new Column(
>                   editTextCell) {
>               @Override
>               public String getValue(Record object) {

```
            return object.getValue();
        }
    };
```

All cells in testColumn are editable.

I want 1st cell of column such way that  1st cell of column should be Non-Editable.

Comment: The first cell of the column is non-editable?  You mean a header?  Why not a header?

Comment: yes 1st cell of 1st column only non editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following class is answer to my question. I Solved it and works fine. But getting error when user clicking on 1st cell of column.

```
class CustomEditTextCell extends EditTextCell{
    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        // context.getColumn()==2 indicate Record ID column and context.getIndex()==0 indicate non editable cell in 1st empty row
        if(context.getColumn()==2 &&    ( context.getIndex()==0  || context.getIndex()%10 == 0)){
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div contentEditable='false' unselectable='true'></div>");
        }else{
        super.render(context, value, sb);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might extend EditTextCell and override the [edit()-Method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.html#edit%28com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29) so that it only edits when you have not set a boolean flag that you that you need to set for the first cell.